# Crystal Report Printing Blank Page With Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I've been working with crystal report but i never found an error like this until now. My crystal report works fine till Crystal Report Viewer. But error when I click Print Button..

[My report When I See From Crystal Report Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbvre.jpg)

[But Got This Error When I Print it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NOia.jpg)

[My Crystal Report Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN3Q0.jpg)

[My Page Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DXyE.jpg)

I Have History Form to show my list before open the Report..
Button to Open the report viewer is

```
Dim i As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim FormViewReport As New FormViewReport()
    Dim rpt As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

    NoFaktur = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value

    rpt = New FakturPartaiLama
    rpt.SetParameterValue(0, NoFaktur)

    FormViewReport.MdiParent = FormUtama 'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
    FormViewReport.Text = "Form View / Print Nota Partai '" & NoFaktur & "'"
    FormViewReport.Show() 'Display the new form.
    FormViewReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    FormViewReport.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    Me.Dispose()
```

Comment: Look at the joining in your database diagram (from database expert). Check whether the joining type is left join rather than inner join. If you use inner join, all records must be present otherwise you get a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you print your report with a pdf-printer instead of a physical printer. Does it work then? Maybe it's an issue with the font.
How do you tell which database to use? Maybe it's not connecting.

Comment: pdf works fine without error.. database is connected. i use default configuration.. just change the paper size to letter fanfold. i use Epson LX310..